# Calculate the Sum of duration in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has two columns start time and end time. I am able to calculate the time duration for each row but I also want to get the total duration. how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your columns are of datatype TIMESTAMP, like this:

```
SQL> create table mytable (start_time,end_time)
  2  as
  3  select to_timestamp('2009-05-01 12:34:56','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  4       , to_timestamp('2009-05-01 23:45:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  5    from dual
  6   union all
  7  select to_timestamp('2009-05-01 23:45:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  8       , to_timestamp('2009-05-02 01:23:45','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
  9    from dual
 10   union all
 11  select to_timestamp('2009-05-01 07:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 12       , to_timestamp('2009-05-01 08:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 13    from dual
 14  /

Tabel is aangemaakt.
```

Subtracting one timestamp from another, leads to an INTERVAL datatype:

```
SQL> select start_time
  2       , end_time
  3       , end_time - start_time time_difference
  4    from mytable
  5  /

START_TIME                     END_TIME                       TIME_DIFFERENCE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
01-05-09 12:34:56,000000000    01-05-09 23:45:01,000000000    +000000000 11:10:05.000000000
01-05-09 23:45:01,000000000    02-05-09 01:23:45,000000000    +000000000 01:38:44.000000000
01-05-09 07:00:00,000000000    01-05-09 08:00:00,000000000    +000000000 01:00:00.000000000

3 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

And INTERVAL datatypes cannot be summed. It's an annoying restriction:

```
SQL> select sum(end_time - start_time)
  2    from mytable
  3  /
select sum(end_time - start_time)
                    *
FOUT in regel 1:
.ORA-00932: inconsistente gegevenstypen: NUMBER verwacht, INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND gekregen
```

To circumvent this restriction, you can convert and calculate with the number of seconds, like this:

```
SQL> select start_time
  2       , end_time
  3       , trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time) days_difference
  4       , to_number(to_char(end_time,'sssss')) - to_number(to_char(start_time,'sssss')) seconds_difference
  5    from mytable
  6  /

START_TIME                     END_TIME                       DAYS_DIFFERENCE SECONDS_DIFFERENCE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------- ------------------
01-05-09 12:34:56,000000000    01-05-09 23:45:01,000000000                  0              40205
01-05-09 23:45:01,000000000    02-05-09 01:23:45,000000000                  1             -80476
01-05-09 07:00:00,000000000    01-05-09 08:00:00,000000000                  0               3600

3 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

And then they are normal NUMBERs that can be summed

```
SQL> select sum
  2         (  86400 * (trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time))
  3          + to_number(to_char(end_time,'sssss')) - to_number(to_char(start_time,'sssss'))
  4         ) total_time_difference
  5    from mytable
  6  /

TOTAL_TIME_DIFFERENCE
---------------------
                49729

1 rij is geselecteerd.
```

And if you wish, you can convert this number back to an INTERVAL:

```
SQL> select numtodsinterval
  2         ( sum
  3           (  86400 * (trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time))
  4            + to_number(to_char(end_time,'sssss')) - to_number(to_char(start_time,'sssss'))
  5           )
  6         , 'second'
  7         ) time_difference
  8    from mytable
  9  /

TIME_DIFFERENCE
------------------------------
+000000000 13:48:49.000000000

1 rij is geselecteerd.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: +1 Very educating, I assumed that trunc() was Oracle's name for round()

Comment: trunc() cuts of the time part of a date/timestamp. Truncating 2009-05-01 23:59:59 leads to 2009-05-01 00:00:00. Rounding leads to 2009-05-02 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the Reply. Its working now by implementing your above code. Thanks again........

Comment: Five years later, still awesome.  This is just what I needed to understand the troubles I was having.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's working! By the way I am shocked that this is the correct answer to this common problem. Dear Oracle this is disgusting. I want my `sum(end_time-start_time)`... :(

Answer (score 3):

This method for Oracle is simple, a bit of a hack though:

```
select sum((end_timestamp+0) - (start_timestamp+0)) 
from your_table
```

Result is a NUMBER of days (with fractional part for hours, minutes and you know).

I don't know what timestamp + 0 does exactly; maybe the ANSI timestamp gets converted to Oracle's earlier timestamp type that allows simple arithmetic.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP + 0` will implicitly cast the `TIMESTAMP` data type to a `DATE` data type (losing the fractional seconds component of the `TIMESTAMP`) and add zero days to it. You could equivalently write your answer as `SELECT SUM( CAST( end_timestamp AS DATE ) - CAST( start_timestamp AS DATE ) ) FROM your_table`. *Note: if your timestamps have fractional second components then this answer will give an incorrect result (and if they don't have fractional seconds why are you storing them as a `TIMESTAMP`?)*.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Added trunc() before summing based on Rob van Wijk's excellent reply.

To find the duration per row:

```
select 
    end_date-start_date as DurationDays, 
    (end_date-start_date)*24 as DurationHours, 
    (end_date-start_date)*24*60 as DurationMinutes, 
    (end_date-start_date)*24*60*60 as DurationSeconds
from your_table
```

To find the total duration:

```
select 
    sum(trunc(end_date-start_date)) as TotalDurationDays
from your_table
```

To do both in one query:

```
select 
    end_date-start_date as DurationDays, 
    (select sum(trunc(end_date-start_date)) from your_table) as TotalDurationDays
from your_table
```

Comment: when i run this query it says that inconsistent datatypes. I am using oracle as the database.

Comment: Can you post the output of "DESCRIBE your_table" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Andomar....I have solved my issue with Rob's help........thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query (it works on an Oracle DB at least):

```
select sum(end_date - start_date) from your_table
```

Comment: when i run this query it says that inconsistent datatypes. I am using oracle as the database.

Comment: This most likely means that your start_date and end_date fields are of different types, but if you say you can calculate the time difference for each row, this might not be the case.

Comment: Can you please paste the SQL that defines the table?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Sevas....I have solved my issue with Rob's help........thanks a lot