# Oracle SQL: Summing HH:MI:SS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following script to sum the duration between the finish of one production order and the start of the next...

```
select mac.name, par.name name_1, ref.name Fehler, count(*) count,
case when 
    to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(log.time_stamp_to - log.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS') 
        > to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:35:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
    then 
        to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:35:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
    else  
        to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(log.time_stamp_to - log.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS')
end duration
from mde_logstate log
right outer join mde_refstate ref
    on log.mach_typ = ref.mach_typ
    and log.part_id = ref.part_id
    and log.state_id = ref.state_id
    and ref.name = 'ORDERCHANGE'
right outer join mde_machpart par
    on log.mach_typ = par.mach_typ
    and log.part_id = par.part_id
right outer join mde_mach mac
    on log.mach_typ = mac.mach_typ 
    and log.mach_id = mac.mach_id 
    and mac.name = 'OFFSET PRINTER NO.3'
where log.mach_typ in ('80','82')
and log.time_stamp_on between to_date('01-05-2017 06:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('01-06-2017 06:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and not 
        (select to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(a1.time_stamp_to-a1.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS')
            from mde_logstate a1, mde_refstate b, mde_machpart d, mde_mach e1
            where a1.mach_typ = log.mach_typ and a1.mach_typ = b.mach_typ and a1.mach_typ = d.mach_typ and a1.mach_typ = mac.mach_typ and a1.mach_id = e1.mach_id
            and a1.part_id = b.part_id and a1.part_id = d.part_id and a1.state_id = b.state_id and b.name = 'PRODUCTION'
            and a1.time_stamp_on between to_date('01-05-2017 06:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('01-06-2017 06:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            and trunc(log.time_stamp_on) = trunc(a1.time_stamp_on) and e1.short_name = mac.short_name) is null
group by log.time_stamp_on, mac.name, par.name, ref.name, mac.mach_typ, log.mach_typ, mac.short_name
```

The case function replaces 'Durations' that are greater than '00:35:00' with '00:35:00'. When the script is run the I get the following 16 line result.

[image]

What i would like to do is remove the 'a.time_stamp_on' from the group by function to leave only the sum of the duration (07:26:55), but when I remove 'a.time_stamp_on' from the group by function I get the following result;

[image]

How do I get the 'Duration' to sum? I tried the following 'sum over partition by', but I get an oracle error (ORA-01722: invalid number):

```
sum(case when 
    to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(a.time_stamp_to - a.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS') 
        > to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:35:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
    then 
        to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:35:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
    else 
        to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(a.time_stamp_to - a.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS')
end) over (partition by e.name)
```

Comment: I think this answer can help you a lot.
[Calculate the Sum of duration in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/892152/2783850)

Comment: Use `DATE '2001-01-01'` instead of `to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` - it is shorter

Comment: I think comparison is simpler `sum(log.time_stamp_to - log.time_stamp_on) > 35/24/60` instead of `to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(sum(log.time_stamp_to - log.time_stamp_on)),'HH24:MI:SS') 
        > to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2001 00:35:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lead` to calculate duration
see sample below

```
with orders as
(select 1 as order_num, sysdate-9 as startdate from dual union all
 select 2 as order_num, sysdate-8 as startdate from dual union all
 select 3 as order_num, sysdate-7 as startdate from dual union all
 select 4 as order_num, sysdate-4 as startdate from dual union all
 select 5 as order_num, sysdate-1 as startdate from dual
)
select order_num, startdate, lead(startdate, 1) over (order by startdate) next_order_start
       ,nvl(lead(startdate, 1) over (order by startdate), startdate) - startdate as duration
 from  orders

    ORDER_NUM   STARTDATE   NEXT_ORDER_START    DURATION
1   1   16/06/2017 17:13:53 17/06/2017 17:13:53 1
2   2   17/06/2017 17:13:53 18/06/2017 17:13:53 1
3   3   18/06/2017 17:13:53 21/06/2017 17:13:53 3
4   4   21/06/2017 17:13:53 24/06/2017 17:13:53 3
5   5   24/06/2017 17:13:53     0
```