# how to sum up minutes and seconds ?in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called `duration_d` which is `varchar2` and the data in that table looks like below

```
duration_d
-----------
12:25
01:35
12:10
04:21
12:18
12:24
```

I tried below query

```
SELECT SUM( to_date( duration_d, 'mi:ss' ))
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY calling_number;
```

When I execute it following error is coming

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

can any one tell me how to make sum it?

Comment: you can't use sum with dates. What values are you expecting when you sum those durations? Ps:one other thing: if you want to use to_date, you have to add the rest of the information, not just the duration: ex: to_date('2000-01-01 00:'||dur,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the Sum of duration in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891833/calculate-the-sum-of-duration-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the total as fractions of a day you can use:

```
SELECT SUM( TO_DATE( duration_d, 'MI:SS' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'MI:SS' ) ) AS total
FROM   your_table
```

Which gives the result:

```
TOTAL
------------------------------------------
0.0383449074074074074074074074074074074074
```

To convert this to an interval data type you can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL`:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
         SUM( TO_DATE( duration_d, 'MI:SS' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'MI:SS' ) ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS total
FROM   your_table
```

Which gives the result:

```
TOTAL
-------------------
+00 00:55:13.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
with x as 
(select sum((regexp_substr(YOUR_COLUMN, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)*60) + 
             regexp_substr(id, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)) seconds 
from YOUR_TABLE)
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(seconds/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(seconds,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(seconds,60),'FM00')
FROM x
```

Will work only if the duration is always [MI:SS].

Also you can add the group by as per your requirement.

Converting Seconds to the required duration format [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003918/oracle-convert-seconds-to-hoursminutesseconds).

Group By

```
with x as 
(select calling_number,sum((regexp_substr(YOUR_COLUMN, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)*60) + 
             regexp_substr(id, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)) seconds 
from YOUR_TABLE
group by calling_number)
SELECT calling_number, 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(seconds/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(seconds,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(seconds,60),'FM00')
FROM x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `SUBSTR`, `to_char`, `to_date`, `NVL`, `INSTR`, `reverse` and `SUM`.

```
SELECT "calling_number",
to_char(to_date(SUM(NVL(SUBSTR("duration_d", 0, INSTR("duration_d", ':')-1), "duration_d"))*60 +
SUM(substr("duration_d", - instr(reverse("duration_d"), ':') + 1)),'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') AS SUM_DURATION_D
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY "calling_number"
```

Output

```
calling_number  SUM_DURATION_D
1               00:26:10
2               00:29:03
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b0a81/33/0

Comment: thank you but i want to do group by calling number group by is not working on it

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: You are multiplying the sum of the minutes by 60 and adding the first character of the sum of the seconds divided by 60 for the first number ... it won't work. You do not need to multiply he minutes by 60 and if the seconds sum to a 4-or-more digit number then you are going to get an incorrect answer. You would do better using `TRUNC` or `FLOOR` and `MOD` to get the minute and second components of the sum of the seconds.

Comment: @MT0 your right, i have re done my answer to allow for any amount of values and also fixed their group by issue

Comment: @bharathRaj try my new anwser

Comment: Or simply: `TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( SUM( SUBSTR( duration_d, 1, 2 ) * 60 + SUBSTR( duration_d, 4, 2 ) ), 'sssss' ), 'hh24:mi:ss' )` *(although it will still give an incorrect answer if the durations sum to more than 24 hours)*

Comment: Thats assuming the minutes will never be bigger than 2 characters, which is why i used the substr instr combo

Comment: If you want to support 3 or more digit minutes then: `TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( SUM( SUBSTR( duration_d, 1, INSTR( duration_d, ':' ) - 1 ) * 60 + SUBSTR( duration_d, -2 ) ), 'sssss' ), 'hh24:mi:ss' )`

Answer (score -1):

Correct spelling as below

```
SELECT SUM( TO_DATE( duration_d, 'mi:ss' ) )
 FROM YOURTABLE Group By calling_number
```

Comment: thank you for the correction but if i run above query its giving this          
 ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: Why to downvote...my repy fixed the problem asked in question.

Comment: thank you but it did not solved the problem @Prathyush